# How to resolve BLE device disconnected after certain hours?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Hi I am working with BLE device connection which is sending data in seconds. With old android versions i.e. before android 26 It was working till 5-6 days. but now with android 26+ it is running 12 or 18 hours which depends on device. I found that GATT_DISCONNECTED called when BLE device is disconnected and I have tried to reconnect device. But because BLE device is not in advertising mode so it is unable to reconnect.

Any one faced same issue or If you have any solution regarding this issue.

Comment: so your device continuously sends data every second. and the connection is lost after 12 - 18 hours?

Comment: yes in android one devices last till 18 hrs and Samsung J7 till 12 hrs

Comment: are you sure the device is sending data continuously every second? what if it stops sending the data after a while, say 12-18 hours. and when there's no read/write operation for a certain period of time, I think the connection automatically times out and disconnects.

Comment: yes device is sending data.. and this could be a reason to disconnect but when i was using target version 23 it was running 28-30 hours but now it reduced to 12-18.

Comment: If anybody used to have this problem, and solved it, please comment the solution